# Customize Sql-Server script generator

Tags: sql-server

in Sql Server there is a function which allows to generate a create script for a complete database.

For some reason i have to create this script without some keys like

- ON [FileGroup] (e. g. ON [PRIMARY])
- PAD_INDEX = [ON | OFF]
- ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = [ON | OFF]
- ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = [ON | OFF]
- SORT_IN_TEMPDB = [ON | OFF]

Is it possible to customize this script generator, to create the script without this keys?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. But you can scipt something to remove them, powershell maybe?

Comment: Thanks, already thought about that, but I wanted to be sure first.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio (2008) go to Tools/Options...
Then follow SQL Server Object Explorer/Scripting path.

I don't know what settings remove your statements but you can check these options.

Comment: Sry there are no options to config these keys.